# Running servlets and cgi/php scripts on the same server

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, cgi

I have a few websites that use cgi(perl) and php scripts.  They run on Cent OS and Apache web server.

I am planning to migrate the cgi scripts to jsp/servlets.  I am hoping that I will use Tomcat for JSP/Servlets.  For some time, I will need to have both cgi scripts and Servlet/JSPs on the same machine.

Since Apache web server will be running on port 80, I am wondering how I can run tomcat without specifying port numbers in the URL.  I looked around if there was an answer to running Apache and Tomcat together.  I could not find one.

I would appreciate an explanation or a link to material where it is explained.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with mod_jk or mod_proxy. Apache on port 80, Tomcat on port 8080, and then depends on your choice (connector):

mod_jk: install mod_jk under apache and activate JK connector in tomcat.

mod_proxy: enable rewrite engine in apache, and set rewrite rules for specified paths (apps) so that apache rewrites requests to your tomcat on port 8080 (http connector).

mod_jk is available to download here: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi

mod_jk documentation, installation and configuration guide is here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/